# Create a CLR (Common Language Runtime) in C#

Tags: c#, sql, frameworks, clr

I need to create a CLR with C# in Visual Studio 2015. The algorithm uses the System.Web.Extensions .dll for convert an string into a JSON with JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(con) method. When I want to add a new assembly into the Database it throws me the next error:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.Web' failed because assembly 
'System.Xaml' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::CanConvertToString][mdToken=0x6000002][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::CanConvertFromString][mdToken=0x6000003][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::ConvertToString][mdToken=0x6000004][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::ConvertFromString][mdToken=0x6000005][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::TypeReferences][mdToken=0x6000006][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::.cctor][mdToken=0x600000d][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::.ctor][mdToken=0x6000001][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::GetSerializerFor][mdToken=0x6000007][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::GetSerializerFor][mdToken=0x6000008][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::GetSerializerFor][mdToken=0x6000009][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::GetSerializerFor][mdToken=0x600000a][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::GetConvertToException][mdToken=0x600000b][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializer::GetConvertFromException][mdToken=0x600000c][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.MemberDefinition::.ctor][mdToken=0x6000010][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
    [ : System.Windows.Markup.PropertyDefinition::get_Name][mdToken=0x6000011][offset 0x00000000] Code size is ze...
```

I dont understand what is the problem, I am not using the Sysmtem.Xaml .dll

I am working with Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio and SQL Server 2012, which have framework 4.0 too.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by creating a CLR? The CLR is provided by Microsoft as far as I know...

Comment: @JamesHughes Based on context, it seems that he's trying to create an assembly in SQL server, thus by CLR, he means SQL CLR.  That said, his question is still unclear.

Comment: Exactly, is an SQL CLR Project in Visual Studio 2015. But SQL Server has a catalog of accepted libraries, and System.Web isnt in there, so I need to add it

Comment: Consider searching SO (or google) for "system.web sql clr". There are quite a number of hits that all seem related.